# when element is removed, then reposition/animate each next element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually I have dynamic notification ".noti", and all has

```
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
 width:250px;
 right://adjusted via jQuery bcz they are dynamically added

 var s = $('body').find('.noti').size();
 xxxxx.css({right:s*250});
```

Now what I want to do is that, when I removed a element, then each next element must reposition/adjust their "right:xxx" property.

for example I have 5 div :

```
 |_ _ _ _ _|
```

and I removed the right most div

```
 |_ _ _ _  |
```

then all other divs must reposition as

```
 |  _ _ _ _|
```

I tried ".next":

```
 var next = $(this).closest('.noti').next('.noti');
 if(next.length > 0){
   var nextright = next.css('right');
   nextright = nextright.split('px').join('');
   next.animate({right:nextright-250},300);
 }
```

but it'll only reposition the next div.

So can somebody tell me that how can I use ".each()" or ".nextAll()" or a "for loop" to reposition all next elements.

Thanks & regards

UPDATE:

Now I tried :

```
 var parent = $(this).closest('.noti'),next = parent.next('.noti');
 var df = parent.attr('data-for');
 if(next.length > 0){
   $('.noti').each(function(){
     if(df != $(this).attr('data-for')){
       var t=$(this),pos = t.css('right');
       pos = pos.split('px').join('');
       t.animate({right:pos-250});
     }
   });
 }
```

Its works good only when I want to remove the right most element. but if I removed any element from the middle, than each ".noti" reposition their "right" property. But I want that only the "nextAll" elements must reposition.

UPDATE : SOLUTION

Finally this problem is solved {solution is based on Tandon's answer} http://jsfiddle.net/7f2aU/5/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/7f2aU/1/) <sup>Click on `div` to remove it</sup>

```
var width = $('#container div').width();

$('#container div').each(function(index){
    // set css property `right` to the width * index (zero-based) + 30 (random number)
    $(this).css("right", ((width * index) + 30));

});

$("#container div").click(function(){
    var thisIndex = $(this).index();  // current element's index
    // console.log(thisIndex); a check

    $(this).siblings("div").each(function(index){ 

        // to make sure the element `$(this)` (the sibling) is to the left of the element clicked on 
        if((index + 1) > thisIndex){

            var css = parseInt($(this).css("right"), 10); // parse the property

            $(this).css("right", css - width); // set it shifted to right by an offset equal to width
            // console.log($(this).css("right")); a check
        }
    });

    $(this).remove(); // finally, remove it
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But Dear I already mentioned that this element has "position:fixed;" css property with jQ adjusted "right:xxx" property.

Comment: @NikitaChaudhary Sorry I did not notice it. I am thinking another solution.

Comment: @NikitaChaudhary Added comments also. Feel free to ask anything you don't understand :)

Comment: Its works great, but it can't fit into my scenario. bcz the "click" function trigger when ".noti > .title > .close" is clicked, and ".noti" itself is a parent div and directly appended to the body {I already mentioned this into the first line of my question}. So, can you modify your solution according to these condition. I'm also trying to do this. Anyways thanks for your help. Please check the update. Thanks & Regards

Comment: Sorry for late response. Here's the fixed fiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/7f2aU/6/

Comment: I don't think I understand what you said. But I can tell that the indexes are `zero-based` i.e. the first element would have an index of `0`.

Comment: In my page, when I add "alert(thisIdex);" just after the "var thisIndex = $(this).closest('.noti').index();", it echo value "8", but when I did this in the fiddle then the value is "0".
It means that the value of "thisIndex" is not zero into my page. So, I have to use "var thisIndex = $(this).closest('.noti').index()-8;" insted of "var thisIndex = $(this).closest('.noti').index();"

Comment: Oh, Yes! I understood what you mean. You need to pass `.index` a selector which will tell it `in which elements' context` does it need to look for the index. See this demonstration --> http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/tFmS5/1/

Comment: So, in your webpage, there are different elements, and you thus got `8` because that element clicked on was `8th` (zero-based) in reference to all other elements. Change the line to `$(this).closest('.noti').index('.noti')` and hopefully it would work.